# how to set key frames on color ramp?

Tags: shaders, keyframes

I am animating a logo.it looks that is hot as a melted iron and gets cold and a blue light turns over that and again turned to red to complete the loop.
In the first frame it should be completely red emmision.then the red get decreased by color ramp until it completely turned off.and then we have blue light and again some spots get red and again turn completely to red.
I wanted to set keyframes to the color ramp but I couldn't.how can I set keyframes for the color ramp?[image]

Comment: if you want to keyframe the needles, keyframe the Pos value, if you want to keyframe the color, you can keyframe the color itself

Comment: thanks dear moonboots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keyframe the needles, keyframe the *Pos* (position) value, if you want to keyframe the color, keyframe the color itself. To keyframe, move your cursor over the value or color and press <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]